# Lazy load (loadChild) returns a blank page angular

Tags: angular, angular5, lazy-loading

I'm working with Angular 5 and i want to implement the Lazy Load but it returns a blank page without any error.

**app-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/content/login/login.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './views/content/error/error.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LoginComponent
},
{
  path: 'operations',
  loadChildren: './views/operations/operations.module#OperationsModule'
},
{
  path: '404',
  component: ErrorComponent
},
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '/404'
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**operations-routing-module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OperationsComponent} from './operations.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OperationsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OperationsRoutingModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log('hola mundo');
  }
}
```

**operation.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OperationsRoutingModule } from './operations-routing';
import { OperationsComponent} from './operations.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, OperationsRoutingModule],
  declarations: [OperationsComponent]
})
export class OperationsModule {}
```

If i use component instead loadChildren the page is showed.

**UPDATE**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavModule } from './views/nav/nav.module';
import { ContentModule } from './views/content/content.module';
import { FooterModule } from './views/footer/footer.module';
import { OperationsModule } from './views/operations/operations.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NavModule,
    ContentModule,
    FooterModule,
    OperationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The rest of the routes (LoginComponent and ErrorComponent) works perfectly, the problem is created by the lazy load. LoginComponent is not empty, just the link to that component is empty, it works like the home of the application.

Comment: Where is your routing for operations in your `OperationsRoutingModule`?

Comment: @penleychan I updated the code of **operations-routing-module.ts**. That's the routing.

Comment: Looks okay to me, you are using angular cli? And you restarted the dev server when you created the operation module?

Comment: is your login.component empty?

Comment: Can you show us your `app.module.ts` and provide an example via stackblitz

Comment: @penleychan : i'm using @angular/cli 6.0.8 and yes, i restarted it a lot of times.

Comment: @hogan : no, it's not empty. the link is empty but the component have content

Comment: @SplitterAlex : i updated the question adding the `app.module.ts` code and i will try to add the project to stackblitz

Comment: You shouldn't import OperationsModule from AppModule: that defeats the whole point of lazy loading.

Comment: @JB Nizet : I deleted it now and the page is loaded know. I don't know how it could be possible because I added it because it didn't work before i added it.

Comment: I assume you added it when testing if it loads when using the eager method. Before, there was probably something else wrong. Well great, it works now.